# Node.JS file upload not retaining files current state on upload

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, file-upload

I have a Node.js server side script that successfully uploads "something" to the specified directory. But it is not my chosen file and the script errors out stating:

```
 Request received: POST
 undefined:1
 ------WebKitFormBoundary1urLweAWe6T1VpEA
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected number
at Object.parse (native)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gcampbell\De
p.js:51:33)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js
at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_common.js:124:22)
```

Here's the file i end up with in my uploads directory.

```
upload_3b2ab28a59131c95015a90a4afe972cd
```

Here's a portion of my **NODE.JS** app:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    console.log('Request received: ' + req.method);

    if (req.method == 'GET') {
        fs.readFile("comments-data.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
                res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                res.end(data)
            }
        })
    };
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
            // create an incoming form object
          var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

          // specify that we want to allow the user to upload multiple files in a single request
          form.multiples = true;

          // store all uploads in the /uploads directory
          form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');

          // every time a file has been uploaded successfully,
          // rename it to it's orignal name
          form.on('file', function(field, file) {
            fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
          });

          // log any errors that occur
          form.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
          });

          // once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client
          form.on('end', function() {
            res.end('success');
          });

          // parse the incoming request containing the form data
          form.parse(req);
        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            var element = JSON.parse(chunk);
            fs.readFile("comments-data.json", 'utf8', function(err, json) {
                var array = JSON.parse(json);
                array.push(element);
                fs.writeFile("comments-data.json", JSON.stringify(array), function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log("The file was saved!");
                });
            });
            res.end('{"msg": "success"}');
        });
    };
```

Here's my **AJAX** call:

```
                uploadAttachments: function(commentArray, success, error) {
                        var responses = 0;
                        var successfulUploads = [];

                        var serverResponded = function() {
                            responses++;

                            // Check if all requests have finished
                            if(responses == commentArray.length) {

                                // Case: all failed
                                if(successfulUploads.length == 0) {
                                    error();

                                // Case: some succeeded
                                } else {
                                    success(successfulUploads)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $(commentArray).each(function(index, commentJSON) {

                            // Create form data
                            var formData = new FormData();
                            $(Object.keys(commentJSON)).each(function(index, key) {
                                var value = commentJSON[key];
                                if(value) formData.append(key, value);
                            });

                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'http://localhost:8080',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: formData,
                                cache: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                success: function(commentJSON) {
                                    successfulUploads.push(commentJSON);
                                    serverResponded();
                                },
                                error: function(data) {
                                    serverResponded();
                                },
                            });
                        });
                    }
```

This is supposed to accept the POST, store the file and update the JSON data in the comments-data.json file to specify where the new file has gone.

Thanks in advance!

The ajax request is a callback function that is used to upload attachments to the server. The first parameter of the callback is commentArray including all the attachments as comment models where file field contains the file to be uploaded. The server should return the url for the uploaded file in fileURL field. The callback provides both success and error callbacks which should be called based on the result from the server. The success callback takes an array of successfull uploads as a parameter.

Comment: Does anyone have anything else that can help?

Answer (score 0):

Often error `undefined:1` is means that you try parse incorrect JSON. Always use `try-catch` when you parse not-safety data e.g. by browser.

```
req.on('data', function(chunk) {
   var element; 
   try {
       element = JSON.parse(chunk);
   } catch(err) {
       return // res status 500, console.log(err), smth-else
   }

   fs.readFile("comments-data.json", 'utf8', function(err, json) {
       // here safety data
       var array = JSON.parse(json);
       array.push(element);
       fs.writeFile("comments-data.json", JSON.stringify(array), function(err) {
           if (err) 
               return console.log(err);

           console.log("The file was saved!");
        });
    });
});
```

---

Try get data from form by

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/',
    data: new FormData($('#your-form-id')[0]),
    processData: false,
    ...
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice on the try, good save. Also, for my ajax request, I'm using a jquery plugin - comments. Therefore, it's not a true form and doesn't exactly have a "form ID" do you have any other suggestions?